# how to reduce the size of the moov atom in mp4 files

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, mp4, x264

For fast streaming, I would like to know how to reduce the size of moov atom (sometimes 2-6 MB). Are there any settings in ffmpeg or x264? I understand the need to reduce the frequency of keyframes, but how would I do it?

Comment: Are you encoding with FFmpeg CLI? The [x264 encoding guide](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide#Overwritingdefaultpresetsettings) has an example for specifying the IDR interval. I don't know how strong the influence will be though, also beware that this might affect the quality and reliability of your stream.

Answer (score 0):

- if you create a "baseline profile" stream, ffmpeg will not put CTTS atom in moov, though the reduction in size will not be significant.
- "mov" file also support something called "cmov" which can reduce the size of moov atom upto 50%, but ffmpeg does not support this (http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=MOV#Decompressing_Compressed_moov_Atoms_With_zlib) you need to use quicktime pro for it, moreover the player support for cmov is also very restrictive.